# Any Way to Use reCAPTCHA v3 instead of v2?

Tags: recaptcha

As title says, is there any way to use v3 instead of v2 for reCAPTCHA?

Comment: Might want to jump in on https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/533 and related https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/2571